# Ansible: escape double curly braces for jinja2 (in quoted expression)

Tags: python, ansible, escaping, jinja2

I have this playbook defined:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ target }}"
  tasks:
    - name: buildout test
      my_buildout:
        cfg: "{
          '/home/oerp/tmp':
            {
              'childs': {
                '{{ custom_name }}': {
                  'rules': [
                    (
                      (),
                      ('cmd', [('touch', {{ get_path('test.txt') }})])
                    )
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
        }"
```

Running my playbook with: `ansible-playbook --extra-vars "target=local_stage" --connection=local /home/oerp/src/ansible-playbooks/buildout_test.yml -v`

Gives this error:

```
fatal: [stage-my-odoo]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'get_path' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/oerp/src/ansible-playbooks/buildout_test.yml': line 4, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - name: buildout test\n      ^ here\n"}
```

Now `{{ custom_name }}` is ansible variable, where `{{ get_path('test.txt') }}`, is Jinja2 expression.

I tried escaping double curly braces for jinja2 expression, like this: `'{{' get_path('test.txt') '}}'`, but it gives same output. So it looks like it still sees it as ansible variable. I also can't remove double quotes wrapping for dict (`cfg` argument type is `dict`) , because then ansible variables are ignored, and it uses literal value (like `{{ custom_name }}`, without replacing with actual value)

P.S. `ansible 2.8.5.post0` `python version = 3.6.7 (default, Mar 29 2019, 10:38:28) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]`

**UPDATE 1**

After `cfg` value is rendered by ansible and passed to module as argument, it is expected to look like this:

```
{
    '/home/oerp/tmp':
    {
      'childs': {
        'my_child_dirname': {
          'rules': [
            (
              (),
              ('cmd', [('touch', "{{ get_path('test.txt') }}")])
            )
          ]
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Then when module receives this value, it is further rendered by jinja2 (specifically `rules` section's items. In this case, `touch` command argument`). It would look something like this:

```
{
    '/home/oerp/tmp':
    {
      'childs': {
        'my_child_dirname': {
          'rules': [
            (
              (),
              ('cmd', [('touch', '/home/oerp/tmp/my_child_dirname/test.txt')])
            )
          ]
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Ansible should only render `{{ custom_name }}`, where `{{ get_path('test.txt') }}` should be left as literal string that would be handled later by my module.

**Update 2**

As it looks confusing what the problem is, I'll try to make it more clear where the issue is.

In `cfg` argument, there are two variables. `custom_name` and `get_path`. First one is normal ansible variable. It should be treated like one and replaced with value by ansible. `get_path` is not ansible variable. It is an expression that becomes variable (call to method), once `my_buildout` module receives rendered `cfg` as argument.

For that reason, `{{ get_path('test.txt') }}` should be treated as simple string by ansible and no conversion is needed (e.g `{{ ansible_ignore_this }}`).
And to make it clear, not whole `cfg` is jinja expression. Only `('touch', {{ get_path('test.txt') }})` this part is rendered by jinja (when module receives whole `cfg`, it iterates over that tuple and tries to render strings: `"touch"` and then `"{{ get_path('test.txt') }}"`.

If `my_buildout` module would receive `cfg` argument directly (without using ansible playbook or whatever) and it would look like the in the first sample in **UPDATE 1**, it then works like a charm.

Comment: Based on your comment on my answer, I have clearly not understood the end-state; can you show a before and after of your `cfg` value? Like I have done: with the things that are variable, and then with them resolved to their final state? Because the data structure as you have presented it cannot become a `dict` without some resolution

Comment: @mdaniel I updated my answer, explaining expected `cfg` state after ansible renders and then after my module renders it (using jinja2).

Comment: wait, after _your module_ renders it? That's not what I asked -- I said what should `cfg` look like before and after, not what does **your module** do with the content; you want ansible to render some content and then you are **also** calling jinja2 to _further_ render the content?

Comment: separately, if that's true about you calling jinja2 again, then, as I correctly pointed out, you can alter the `variable_start_string` and `variable_end_string` in **your module** to further distinguish between ansible's start expression and **your** start expression

Comment: @mdaniel didn't I showed you how cfg should look like before and after? To make it more clear, I showed what it also looks like after such cfg is used by module. If you don't care what my module does, then you can ignore the last sample, but It does not look like you understood where the problem is. You should take a note in part I said "(specifically rules section's items. In this case, touch command argument)". Only this part is rendered in my module, where each part of tuple is rendered. In this case `touch` and `{{get_path..}}`. I will update my question further if its not clear.

Answer (score 0):

*updated for the new question content*

Since `cfg` needs to be a `dict`, it doesn't make sense to use a string literal for that content -- in other words, you don't want jinja2 mustache expressions, you want to use the *variables* in the places that are *variable*:

```
- name: buildout test
  my_buildout:
    cfg: >-
      {{
      {
        '/home/oerp/tmp': {
          'childs': {
             custom_name: {
               'rules': [
                (
                  (),
                  ('cmd', [('touch', get_path('test.txt') )])
                )
               ]
             }
          }
        }
      }
      }}
```

Comment: Tried both approaches, but it gives this error (in both cases): `fatal: [stage-my-odoo]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "argument cfg is of type <class 'str'> and we were unable to convert to dict: unable to evaluate string as dictionary"}`. It somehow makes argument as invalid dict.

Comment: I think it complicates matters more, because `'test.txt'` need to be quote it.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hopefully it will make it clear where the issue is. I also tried your updated answer, but it will give this error: `The offending line appears to be:

      {{
      {
      ^ here`. Though as I mentioned multiple times, only part of `cfg` is rendered by jinja2, so I was not expecting this to work.